# Why am I getting an assertion error even though the return value is the same?

Tags: python-2.7, assert

I test my code with these elements and got 4.6, but when I tried it assert, the interpreter return an assertion error.

```
def function(x):
    a = 0
    x.remove(min(x))
    x.remove(max(x))
    for i in x:
        a = a + i
    return float(1)/len(x)*a

assert function([3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 4]) == 4.6
```

Comment: `print function([3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 4])` gives `8.388608e-17`.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I made a mistake in my code, but the code still got an assertion error.

Comment: Try `assert abs(function(...) - 4.6) < 0.001` - it could be a float precision issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet, but it looks like @jonsharpe is right. there is a float precision issue. I put in `print abs(test - 4.6) < 0.001` and that returned true. I also imported unittest and used assertEqual (I'll post the code below:

```
import unittest
def function(x):
    a = 0
    x.remove(min(x))
    x.remove(max(x))
    for i in x:
        a = a + i
    return float(1)/len(x)*a

tc = unittest.TestCase('__init__')
tc.assertEqual(function([3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 4]), 4.6)
```

From creating an instance of a test case and running this it showed a bit more of what the underlying error is. Here is what I got as a result from running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
  tc.assertEqual(function([3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 4]), 4.6)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 515, in assertEqual
  assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 508, in _baseAssertEqual
  raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 4.6000000000000005 != 4.6
```

I hope this can help you figure out your problem and find a solution to this!

Comment: unittest has an assertAlmostEqual() function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual